# Is playing the card game Tetra Master required for completion of the game?

Tags: final-fantasy-9

Both of my computers died last weekend so I unearthed my PS2 and peeled the plastic off of a copy of Final Fantasy 9.
I started worrying when the first item in the game that I found was a card, and sure enough within 30 minutes I was being walked through the successor to Triple Triad, the minigame/mechanic I hate most in the FF universe.

Can I safely ignore this part of the game without missing a key scene/character/spell/item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tetra Master games do not give you anything except more cards to play Tetra Master, even the tournament.

The cards themselves do not convert into any items like they did with Triple Triad.  There is collection level that increases, but doesn't award anything except ranking.  So the only thing lost by not playing Tetra Master, is Tetra Master.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, no you cannot ignore the game completely as you must win at least two rounds during Disk 3 when you go to the Card Tournament.